# SQLdroid - online access?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have integrated SQLdroid ([sqldroid.org](http://sqldroid.org)) into my project. I am connecting locally with my SQLite database in Android. Is there any way how to connect to online SQLite database file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SQLDroid is not the path because it's designed only to access the built-in SQLite database, in fact it uses the standard Android SQLite API